# how to solve something associated with memory and speed of my computer?

Tags: matlab, memory, cpu

first of all , i have a specific task that works at the expense of every possible combination of range , i already used a program that perform my purpose this code is :

```
  clc
clear
a = input('Please, select your array: ')
b = a(:).'
c = length(b)
for d =1:c
if (d<c)
  e{d} = nchoosek(b, d);
end
end
tt=cellfun(@(m) padarray(m,[0 max(cellfun(@(n) size(n,2), e)) - size(m,2)],'post'),     e,'UniformOutput',0);
uu=cell2mat(tt([1:d-1])')
suu=size(uu)
uu(:,((suu(2))+1))=sum(uu')'
```

but i faced a big problem during the implementation of the program that this command :

```
e{d} = nchoosek(b, d)
```

has failed to continue as result of the number of possible choices and number of selected choices and finally the limitations:

When `b = nchoosek(n,k)` is sufficiently large, `nchoosek` displays a warning that the result might not be exact. In this case, the result is only accurate to 15 digits for double-precision inputs, or 8 digits for single-precision inputs.

`C = nchoosek(v,k)` is only practical for situations where length(v) is less than about 15.

that's where my vector consist of the hundreds of numbers which i want to do this process on.
when i run the program , then matlab is being busy until giving me out of memory error in a time and takes along time without implementation of the program then i am forced to out of the program . i looked for a solution by help "out of memory" but i failed to find any solution then i tried to use another command that's

```
combnk(v,k)
```

but it takes along time without implementation of the program then i am forced to out of the program too
please please please , i want to practical solution to perform a lot of processes like this for my work .
If the solution depends on the capabilities of my computer tell me about that computer specifications which performs this program easily , quickly and immediately 
note that my computer specifications are :
win 7
64 bit
4 GB RAM
2.3 cpu i3

Comment: If your vector `b` is length 100, then at some point in that loop you're asking for every combination of 50 out of 100 numbers - that's around 10^29 combinations.  Is that really what you need to do?

Comment: yes,something like that

Comment: You should rethink your algorithm, then. Just a simple back of the envelope calculation of how much memory you'd need to store all those combinations at once should show you why.

Comment: already i did that i need to solution my dear

Comment: There is literally not enough memory in the known universe to do what you are attempting to do. You are trying to store more bits of information than there are electrons in the entire planet Earth. It won't work.

Comment: @beaker It's not nearly that much. The number of atoms on earth is ~10^50 (and the number of known stars is/was ~10^22).

Comment: @user2864740 So it is! (The things you learn...) And "the known universe" is a bit of a cheat because the only storage devices we know about are the ones we've invented ourselves. Anyhow, it still won't work. :)

Comment: @beaker It is indeed an unfeasible approach as proposed :)